# Can apache startup run a script to populate environment?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, apache2, aws-secrets-manager, aws-php-sdk

We're moving a website to the AWS environment and running apache2 on an EC2. We were planning on using the AWS secrets manager to store some of the credentials such as the RDS (database) and email credentials.  I also use environment variables in apache to store the AWS credentials, but since it is the AWS credentials which are used to retrieve the secrets, I was wondering if there was any way to run a script on apache start-up to use the aws-sdk to retrieve those secrets.

Or are there any other suggestions on how to do it? I can do it after the fact in the PHP code that needs such access, but I'm just exploring what is possible at the moment.  It would be nice if some configuration options were loaded when apache starts.

Comment: So is the requirement you want to generate your apache environment variables from your secrets manager config? :)

Comment: basically run a php script to fetch some values via the aws-sdk. Can I do that by modifying the apache2.service (systemd) with a ExecStartPre=?

Comment: a crap, but that won't work because then I'd need to find some way to get the aws credentials to it. (they're available via the apache2 environment from the site config)

Comment: If you're running on an EC2 instance you should use an IAM role over IAM credentials, regarding pre populating its probably best to try and avoid touching the files apache creates. I don't suppose creating a small script that could either be run at deploy time of your code or on a cron is possible? Is there any specific reason why it must be on Apache startup? :)

Comment: I'm trying to get credentials from AWS Secrets to add to environment variables available to php scripts run in apache.

Comment: ugh, now SetEnv isn't even working - I'm assuming those are supposed to be available to php in $_ENV? I did a simple apache SetEnv and I don't see anything in $_ENV when a php script runs.

Comment: ExecStartPre didn't work, presumably because the environment I'm setting is dumped before the apache startup begins.  I'm guessing I would have to write my own script around apachectl to invoke that and still have the environment available

Comment: They might appear under `$_SERVER`, for $_ENV you need to ensure you php ini settings are configured to use it :)

Comment: I was able to use PassEnv with a modification to apachectl to get the variable in there, but now the problem is that it's a shell environment and the only way I could get it set in a shell environment variable is as a single scalar (string) value. So I have to serialize it or otherwise turn it into a delimited string.

Answer (score 0):

Your two options seem to be either write a startup script that populates the env variables and then starts apache as a child process so it can read those variables, or modify the web application to read the secrets directly.

Reading the secrets directly in the application (possibly from some short lived cache) would allow you to rotate your DB creds without having to restart the application.

Also, if you are running on EC2 you do not need to populate env variables with the AWS creds. Just use [roles for EC2](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_roles_use_switch-role-ec2.html). The AWS CLI and SDKs already know how to retrieve those credentials directly.

Comment: so basically "no"

Comment: Correct, but it seems like using roles for EC2 should be easiest alternative.

Comment: yup, changing to that method now